# Can a Wordpress Theme be ported to Tumblr? If yes, how?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, tumblr

I want to port a Wordpress theme - with all it's functionalities (e.g. auto fitting depending on browser window size, iOS version, etc.) - over to Tumblr.

Why? Because I think this theme is superior to any other I have seen. And because IMO Tumblr is better than Wordpress (I'm not smart enough for Wordpress).

Answer (score 2):

nope, unless yo do it by hand :). Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

if by "porting" you mean just take it and use it as-is , the answer is no like @SnippetSpace answered.

If by "porting" you mean "replicating" by re-write code and functions to "mimic" the same looks and functionality (to a certain back-side limits) then the answer is of course you can.

Usually it will amount to a lot of work, basically re-writting a whole new theme.
What you will be "porting" at that point is the design, feel and looks of the theme - not it´s functions - those will have to be written bottom-up.